# How do I add more than 6 items to my Chrome extension's action menu?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been working on a Chrome extension and adding custom options such as radio buttons to the contxtmenu. After I add six items in my background.js, using the chrome.contextMenus.create command, any subsequent items I add are ignored. I understand that there's a default limit of 6 context menu items you can add, but there's also this command:

chrome.contextMenus.ACTION_MENU_TOP_LEVEL_LIMIT.

I tried setting this to chrome.contextMenus.ACTION_MENU_TOP_LEVEL_LIMIT = 10, but the limit remained at 6. Is there any way to change the limit so I can add more than 6 items?

Comment: No, you will need to nest them.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to change the limit so I can add more than 6 items?

No, this is a constant set by API. As you noticed, changes are ignored - it's only provided so you can use it in your code as a limiter in case that ever changes (to avoid 6 as a ["magic number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)).

Note that it only limits the **top level** items: therefore, you can create a cascading menu (by specifying `parentId` in `create`) that does not have this limitation.